# trying to add data and query a mysql database using sqlobject and python 3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlobject

My code is raising an exception as shown below.  I am pretty sure the problem is with my definition of the table relationship.  I have tried multiple alternatives that give varying errors :-(

I have a License that can have one or more MacAddresses as follows:

```
class MacAddress(sqlobject.SQLObject):
    # noinspection PyPep8Naming,PyClassHasNoInit
    class sqlmeta:
        table = "mac_address_table"

    mac_address = sqlobject.StringCol(unique=True, length=50)
    license = sqlobject.ForeignKey('License', default=None)


class License(sqlobject.SQLObject):
    # noinspection PyPep8Naming,PyClassHasNoInit
    class sqlmeta:
        table = "license_table"

    user_name = sqlobject.StringCol(unique=True, length=50)
    mac_addresses = sqlobject.MultipleJoin('MacAddress')

    @staticmethod
    def create(user_name, mac_address):
        lic = License(user_name=user_name)
        mac = MacAddress.get(mac_address)
        lic.add_mac_address(mac)
        return lic

    def add_mac_address(self, mac_address):
        mac_address.license = self

    @staticmethod
    def is_valid(user_name, mac_address):
        query = License.selectBy(user_name=user_name)
        found = False
        if query.count() != 0:
            lic = query.getOne()
            # Here is where I am having a problem:
            for mac in lic.mac_addresses:
                if mac.mac_address == mac_address:
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                return True
        return False
```

When I try to test a License like this:

```
lic.is_valid(user_name="Fred", mac_address="1234"),
```

I get an error at this line:
            for mac in lic.mac_addresses:

I get the following error:

```
sqlobject.dberrors.OperationalError: Unknown column 'license_table_id' in 'where clause'
```

I have the following tables in the database:

mac_address_table:

```
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| license_table_id     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| mac_address_table_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

license_table:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_name | varchar(50) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

mac_address_table_license_table:

```
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| license_table_id     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| mac_address_table_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here are the contents of the database:

```
    select * from license_table; select * from mac_address_table; select * from license_table_mac_address_table;
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| id | user_name | password | created             |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Fred      | xxx      | 2019-04-29 17:59:47 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)


+----+-------------+------------+
| id | mac_address | license_id |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 | 1234        |          1 |
+----+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------------------+----------------------+
| license_table_id | mac_address_table_id |
+------------------+----------------------+
|                1 |                    1 |
+------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

`SQLObject` needs to know the join column. Help it a bit:

```
class License(sqlobject.SQLObject):
    class sqlmeta:
        table = "license_table"

    user_name = sqlobject.StringCol(unique=True, length=50)
    mac_addresses = sqlobject.MultipleJoin('MacAddress', joinColumn='license_id')
```

the key part here is `joinColumn='license_id'`.

PS. Not directly related to your question:

```
    if query.count() != 0:
        lic = query.getOne()
```

Here you run the query two times. I recommend optimization:

```
    try:
        lic = query.getOne()
    except sqlobject.SQLObjectNotFound:
        return False
    else:
        for mac in lic.mac_addresses:
            …
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response!  I added the joinColumn as you suggested, now I get TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given at the same location

Comment: I also like your optimization and have incorporated it!

Comment: `TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument` I'd like to see the entire traceback. Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have fixed it:

```
class MacAddress(sqlobject.SQLObject):
    # noinspection PyPep8Naming,PyClassHasNoInit
    class sqlmeta:
        table = "mac_address_table"

    value = sqlobject.StringCol(unique=True, length=50)
    license = sqlobject.ForeignKey('License', default=None)


class License(sqlobject.SQLObject):
    # noinspection PyPep8Naming,PyClassHasNoInit
    class sqlmeta:
        table = "license_table"

    user_name = sqlobject.StringCol(unique=True, length=50)
    mac_addresses = sqlobject.MultipleJoin('MacAddress', joinColumn='license_id')

    @staticmethod
    def create(user_name, mac_address):
        lic = License(user_name=user_name)
        lic.add_mac_address(mac_address=mac_address)
        return lic

    def add_mac_address(self, mac_address):
        mac_address.license = self

    @staticmethod
    def is_valid(user_name, mac_str):
        query = License.selectBy(user_name=user_name)
        found = False
        if query.count() != 0:
            lic = query.getOne()
            for mac in lic.mac_addresses:
                if mac_str == mac.value:
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                return True
        return False
```

And this is working fine now:

```
def test_license():
    mac_address = MacAddress(value="123")
    lic = License.create(user_name="Fred", mac_address=mac_address)
    mac_address = MacAddress(value="2468")
    lic.add_mac_address(mac_address=mac_address)
    print(lic.is_valid(user_name="Fred", mac_str=mac_address.value))
    print(lic.is_valid(user_name="Fred", mac_str="3456"))
```

I have no idea what I did to rectify this unless it was something silly like over-riding the SQLObject get method in MacAddress...
Thanks for your help.